# Lua - Table in a Table Printing and Sorting

Tags: lua

```
T = {
{Name = "Mark", HP = 54, Breed = "Ghost"},
{Name = "Stan", HP = 24, Breed = "Zombie"},
{Name = "Juli", HP = 100, Breed = "Human"}},
```

Questions:

How would I Print just the names?

and

How can I sort it by HP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the table by using either the `pairs` or `ipairs` function to print the name.  `ipairs` iterates from 1 to N (numeric indices only), while `pairs` iterates over *every* element, in no defined order.

```
> T = { {Name = "Mark", HP = 54, Breed = "Ghost"}, {Name = "Stan", HP = 24, Breed = "Zombie"}, {Name = "Juli", HP = 100, Breed = "Human"}}
> for _,t in ipairs(T) do print(t.Name) end
Mark
Stan
Juli
```

Then you can use the [`table.sort`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial) function to sort the table *in-place*:

```
> table.sort(T, function(x,y) return x.HP < y.HP end)
> for _,t in ipairs(T) do print(t.Name, t.HP) end
Stan    24
Mark    54
Juli    100
```

The second argument to `table.sort` is a comparison function of your choice; in this case, we only wanted to compare the HP values.

Comment: You have reversed the meanings for `ipairs()` and `pairs()`.  `ipairs()` iterates the numeric indices, and `pairs()` iterates over every element.